# how to get a count of adding records in another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i'm developing a product management system. in my project there is two modules as products(which is using tbl_product table in DB & have a column named as count) & supply(which is using tbl_supply table in DB).

the thing which i wanted to know is how to increase the count of the products in the tbl-product when inserting products using supply module.

i wrote the insert function but i couldn't write the update function to increase the count

if someone can help to solve this i'll be very thankful

Comment: Dont keep counts in tables like that. The likelyhood is they will amost always be wrong. If you want to know a count then do a query to get the count when you need it. For example, you go in to the database with phpMyAdmin to fix a woops. You will always forget to amend the count in that sort of situation

Answer (score 0):

When you add a supply in table.
Run a query to increase count = count + 1 Like that.

UPDATE tbl_product SET count=count+1 WHERE product_id=product_id